# Fluent navigation with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one single-page application with three sub-pages.

Url structure is:

```
/page  (sub-page-0)

/page#sub-page-1

/page#sub-page-2
```

View Model is:

```
function ViewModel(activePage){
   var self=this;

   self.activePage=ko.observable(activePage);
   self.changePage=function (newPage){
       self.activePage(newPage);
       //change url
   });
}
```

When user enter url I want to get # part in javascript and construct ViewModel with this parameter.

When user click link in the page I want to change URL and load that sub page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use one of the solutions from the stack overflow question: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

However, I strongly recommend you consider a client side routing library. The knockout homepage has an [example](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) using [sammyjs](http://sammyjs.org/), but there are many other interesting solutions out there (including [knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/%20KnockBackJS), which combines backbonejs and knockoutjs).

Answer (score 3):

Knockout itself does not support navigation. But you can use third party frameworks. There is a tutorial named "Single page applications" from knockout at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ which shows how to do that with sammy.js.